# Setting ngModel using ng-clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there some reason when I save the input from an Angular form of checkboxes that I cannot get ng-model on the controller to become defined when I set the values on the checkboxes with ng-checked? Basically, I need to save the values in an array and if a user returns to the page it should set the form to the values stored in the array. Here is a plnkr of my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/l1tIWwaYWsyKou64VjrO

Here is the function that ng-checked calls when the user returns to the page:

```
function getChecked(id) {

        if (businessApp.serviceTypes.indexOf(id) > -1)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

The list of services is stored in the array businessApp.serviceTypes.

Comment: Not sure about how your code is setup, but one error i found is with setting `ng-true-value='{{key}}'`, it should be `ng-true-value="key"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.  Basically it stores the checks (in the order they are displayed on the page).  I added a toggle to ng-click to change the value stored in the array.  I would recommend you modify your model to accommodate a more convenient way of storing the checks though, because right now your labels are sorted, so they come out a different order in the view than they are stored in the model.

Just added this to the controller:

```
self.checks = {
        vals: [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]
      }
```

HTML I changed/added this:

```
ng-checked="vm.checks.vals[$index]"
ng-model="vm.serviceType[$index]"
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/EA7JZX5L0lMH9lPprwID?p=preview)